# Laplacian eigenvalues of a solid torus

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian

Is it possible to find an analytical solution for eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Dirichlet Laplacian on a solid torus?
More precisely, is it possible to solve analytically the following problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = \lambda u \\ 
u|_{\partial T} = 0
\end{cases}
$$

where T is a solid torus ($T=S^1 \times D$, $S^1$ is a circle and D is a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$).
I have found a method of separation of Laplace’s equation in toroidal coordinates in "Alternative separation of Laplace’s equation in toroidal coordinates and
its application to electrostatics" (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.elstat.2005.11.005), but I'm not quite sure if it is applicable in this case (the eigenvalue problems are not considered in this article).

Comment: I have found out that the Helmholtz equation is not separable in toroidal coordinates, but maybe there is another way to solve the problem?